# Creating a Grade Book with classes - Python

Tags: python, class, oop, attributes, instance

I'm working on a project/exercise where I need to use OOP in Python to create a Grade Book. I've been learning Python and working with 3.8.3 for about 6 weeks now, so I'm still fairly new. The grade book has a basic menu where you can add an assignment, quiz, and final exam grades. I must use a class with an empty list for both the quiz and assignment grades. I did a rough draft of the code after reading a bit on OOP, and managed to get the class to function without using attributes and only one method as below:

```py
class GradeBook:
    
    def main_function():
        quiz_scores = []
        assignment_scores = []
        while True:
            try:
                quiz_grade = float(input('Please enter a grade for the quiz, or press Enter to stop adding grades: '))
                quiz_scores.append(quiz_grade)
            except:
                break

        while True:
            try:
                assignment_grade = float(input('Please enter a grade for the assignment, or press Enter to stop adding grades: '))
                assignment_scores.append(assignment_grade)
            except:
                break
    
        print (quiz_scores)
        print (assignment_scores)
        print ('time for totals and averages')
    
        quiz_total = sum(quiz_scores)
        assignment_total = sum(assignment_scores)
        print ('quiz total ' + str(quiz_total))
        print ('assign total ' + str(assignment_total))

        if len(quiz_scores) > 0:
            quizScoreAverage = sum(quiz_scores)// len(quiz_scores) 
        else:
            quizScoreAverage = 0
    
        if len(assignment_scores) > 0:
            assignmentScoreAverage = sum(assignment_scores) // len(assignment_scores)
        else:
            assignmentScoreAverage = 0

        print ('quiz average ' + str(quizScoreAverage))
        print ('assign average ' + str(assignmentScoreAverage))


        
GradeBook.main_function()
```

Here is where I am running into my issues. I need to split the code up into several methods/functions, one for quiz scores, one for assignment scores, one that will store the final exam score and do nothing more, and one for getting the current grade/average. I've been searching and searching but have hit a wall. The code works up until I attempt to append the user's input to the list in the class. Again this is just a rough draft of the code as follows:

```py
class GradeBook:
    # Need this at attribute level for all instances to acccess as there will be an instance the pulls the list to calculate overall grade
    assignment_scores = []
    # quiz_scores = [] ### - This is the other list that will also be used for the grade
    def assignGrade(self, score):
        self.score = score
        self.assignment_scores.append(score)
#####################################################
              
'''
This will be a duplicate of the above code but will use values to store quiz grades instead

    def quizGrade(self, score):
        self.score = score
        self.quiz_scores.append(score)
'''
#####################################################

while True:
    try:
        assignment_grade = float(input('Please enter a grade for the assignment, or press Enter to stop adding grades: '))

        # Program works just fine up until this point. My issue is here. Trying to feed the user input into the class instance
        # to update the class list that is stored as an attribute. Instead of appending it seems to throw an error,
        # because it doesn't continue the try loop for input and after the break when the list is printed, no values are shown

        assignment_grade = GradeBook.assignGrade(assignment_grade) # <------- THIS IS THE PROBLEM CHILD OF MY CODING
    except:
        break
#####################################################
    
''' This block will be used to get input for the quiz grade to append to quiz scores list
while True:
    try:
        quiz_grade = float(input('Please enter a grade for the assignment, or press Enter to stop adding grades: '))
        quiz_grade = GradeBook.quizGrade(quiz_grade) #not sure if this is right?
    except:
        break
'''
#####################################################
```

I guess I'm just not getting a good grasp on the whole idea of sending information from one instance to another. Any input is greatly appreciated. My plan is once it all gets figured out I just need to plug in the code to my final draft here:

```py
class GradeBook:
    # Initializes empty list to store quiz and assignment grades
    quiz_scores = []
    assignment_scores = []

    #####################################################
    def quizScore(self, score)
        # lines of code to append user input to quiz list for reference in class

    #####################################################
    def assignScore(self, score)
         # lines of code to append user input to assignment list for reference in class
                
    #####################################################
    def finalScore(self, score)
         # line of code to store the final exam grade for reference in the class

    #####################################################
    def currentAverage(self)
        if len(self.assignment_scores) > 0:
            assignmentScoreAverage = sum(self.assignment_scores) // len(self.assignment_scores)
        else:
            assignmentScoreAverage = 0

        if len(self.quiz_scores) > 0:
            quizScoreAverage = sum(self.quiz_scores) // len(self.quiz_scores) 
        else:
            quizScoreAverage = 0

        currentGrade = (0.4 * self.final_grade) + (0.3 * quizScoreAverage) + (0.3 * assignmentScoreAverage)
        return currentGrade

#####################################################
print('''
Grade Book

0: Exit
1: Enter assignment grade
2: Enter quiz grade
3: Enter final exam grade
4: Display current grade

''')
while True:
    try:
        selection = int(input('Please enter a choice: '))
        if selection == 0:
            quit
        elif selection == 1:
            while True:
                try:
                    assignment_grade = float(input('Please enter a grade for the assignment, or press Enter to stop adding grades: '))
                    GradeBook.assignScore(assignment_grade)
                except:
                    break
                
        elif selection == 2:
            while True:
                try:
                    quiz_grade = float(input('Please enter a grade for the assignment, or press Enter to stop adding grades: '))
                    GradeBook.quizScore(quiz_grade)
                except:
                    break
        elif selection == 3:
            while True:
                try:
                    final_grade = float(input('Please enter a grade for the assignment, or press Enter to stop adding grades: '))
                    GradeBook.finalScore(final_grade)
                except:
                    break
        elif selection == 3:
            final_grade = float(input('Please enter a grade for the final exam: '))
                    if isdigit(final_grade)
                        GradeBook.finalScore(final_grade)
                    else:
                        print('Please check your input and try again.')
        elif selection == 4:
            print(GradeBook.currentAverage())
        else:
            print('Please check your input and try again.')
            continue
```

Answer (score 0):

(Please, use snake case for all your code, including methods. Camel case should only be used for classes) In python I would recommend creating a module(file) without class for your main function. You are using the assignGrade method as a class method. Actually, you never even created an instance of your class! To create an instance, you should call the class as follows:

```
my_grades = GradeBook()
```

Now, my_grades is "a variable"(an instance) that contains all the properties(attributes) you defined for your class. You can access them as follows:

```
my_grades.assignment_scores
```

Your loop will fail because you have not passed the self argument to the function you pointed as the problem. In python, all instance methods start with the self argument, but it will be the variable(instance) before the dot. So, you should call it from an instance of your class and not from the class itself. Using the one I created from the first example, you can change the line to:

```
my_grades.assignGrade(assignment_grade)
```

That should do.

Instead of creating and calling a main_function, in the module add the following:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ... # Create your instances and manipulate them here
```

Comment: I appreciate the info, I'll take a look into it tomorrow. I was unaware of difference in naming conventions (snake and camel) as I've only been going through Automate the Boring Stuff and Python Fundamentals for 6 weeks. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Take a look at PEP8. It has all style conventions for Python. It's a long document, I recommend you take a look at the variables part, at least

Answer (score 0):

So following the guidelines that were provided to us, as well as the example inputs, I have the program working as intended. Since this was just an introduction class, we didn't get into using methods in separate files, so I did not use:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

However, I would like any comments on it like readability and other coding practices. Working code below:

```py
# Programmed by thelastesquire92
# Programming Assignment 7 - Grade Book App
# SEC290.B2.32789

'''
Program that focuses on Object Oriented Programming.
The user is presented with simple text menu, and following
input prompts they are allowed to enter grades for quizzes,
assignments, and a final exam. The program then calculates
the average grade based off of these inputs.
'''

class GradeBook:
    # Initializes empty list for quiz and assignment grades, sets default final score to 0
    quiz_scores = []
    assignment_scores = []
    final_exam_score = 0
    
    #####################################################
    # Adds grade input to list of quiz scores
    def quiz_score(self, score):
        self.quiz_scores.append(score)
        
    #####################################################
    # Adds grade input to list of assignment scores
    def assignment_score(self, score):
        self.assignment_scores.append(score)
        
    #####################################################
    # Updates value of final exam score
    def final_score(self, score):
        GradeBook.final_exam_score = score
    
    #####################################################
    # Calculates current grade average 
    def current_average(self):
        if len(GradeBook.assignment_scores) > 0:
            assignment_score_average = sum(GradeBook.assignment_scores)\
                                       // len(GradeBook.assignment_scores)
        else:
            assignment_score_average = 0

        if len(GradeBook.quiz_scores) > 0:
            quiz_score_average = sum(GradeBook.quiz_scores)\
                                 // len(GradeBook.quiz_scores) 
        else:
            quiz_score_average = 0

        current_grade = (0.4 * GradeBook.final_exam_score)\
                        + (0.3 * quiz_score_average)\
                        + (0.3 * assignment_score_average)
                        
        return current_grade

#####################################################
# Prints out the menu for user
menu = ('''
Grade Book

0: Exit
1: Enter assignment grade
2: Enter quiz grade
3: Enter final exam grade
4: Display current grade
''')
print(menu)

#####################################################
# Main body of program that loops until user selects option to exit
while True:
    # Creates instance of GradeBook
    my_grades = GradeBook()
    try:
        selection = int(input('\nPlease enter a choice: '))

        #####################################################
        # Option 0 that exits the program
        if selection == 0:
            break

        #####################################################
        # Option 1 that allows input for assignment grades
        elif selection == 1:
            while True:
                try:
                    assignment_grade = float(input('\nPlease enter a grade for the assignment: '))
                    my_grades.assignment_score(assignment_grade)
                    break
                except:
                    print('\nPlease check your input and try again.')
                    continue
                
        #####################################################
        # Option 2 that allows input for quiz grades
        elif selection == 2:
            while True:
                try:
                    quiz_grade = float(input('\nPlease enter a grade for the quiz: '))
                    my_grades.quiz_score(quiz_grade)
                    break
                except:
                    print('\nPlease check your input and try again.')
                    continue

        #####################################################
        # Option 3 that allows input for final exam grade
        elif selection == 3:
            while True:
                try:
                    final_grade = float(input('\nPlease enter a grade for the final exam: '))
                    my_grades.final_score(final_grade)
                    break
                except:
                    print('\nPlease check your input and try again.')
                    continue

        #####################################################
        # Option 4 that displays current grade average
        elif selection == 4:
            average = my_grades.current_average()
            print('\nYour current grade average is: ' + str(average))
        else:
            print('\nPlease check your input and try again.')
            continue
    except:
        print('\nPlease check your input and try again.')
        print(menu)
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def setup_gradebook(old_gradebook):
  # Use a dictionary method to create a new copy of the "old_gradebook".
  new_gradebook = old_gradebook.copy() 
    # Complete the for loop to iterate over the new gradebook. 
  for key in new_gradebook:
        # Use a dictionary operation to reset the grade values to 0.
      new_gradebook[key] = 0
  return new_gradebook

fall_gradebook = {"James": 93, "Felicity": 98, "Barakaa": 80}
print(setup_gradebook(fall_gradebook))
# Should output {'James': 0, 'Felicity': 0, 'Barakaa': 0}
```